# How can I print the value of the list element that storing/referencing the address/location?

Tags: python, list

```py
class Mobile:
    def __init__(self,brand,price):
        self.brand = brand
        self.price = price

mob1=Mobile("Apple", 1000)
mob2=Mobile("Samsung", 5000)
mob3=Mobile("Apple", 3000)

mob_dict = {
          "m1":mob1,
          "m2":mob2,
          "m3":mob3
          }

lit = []

for key,value in mob_dict.items():
    if value.price > 3000:
        lit.append(value)
        print (value.brand,value.price)
print(lit)
```

Output:

```
[<__main__.Mobile object at 0x000001C45C721100>]
```

Please explain why am getting this output.

Comment: What else would you *expect*?

Comment: Looks like you're appending a class object. Wouldn't you want to append either value.brand, value.price, or some combination thereof?

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the whole object, you can do `print(lit[0])` or:

```
for elem in lit:
    print(elem)
```

Comment: That would also just output <__main__.Mobile ...>…